# How to describe $\lbrace \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R^n}: |x_j|\le1 $ for$ 1\le j\le n \rbrace $ in terms of $x_j=x_j^+-x_j^-$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, optimization, convex-analysis, linear-programming

How to describe the set $A$=$\lbrace \mathbf{x}\in \mathbb{R^n}: |x_j|\le1 $ for$ 1\le j\le n  \rbrace $ in terms of $x_j=x_j^+-x_j^-$ where $x_j^+\ge0$ and $x_j^-\ge0$

The answer says:
$B$=$\lbrace (\mathbf{x^+},\mathbf{x^-}): x_j^+ +x_j^-\le 1, x_j^+\ge0,x_j^-\ge0 $ $for $ $ j=1,..,n \rbrace$

But $x_j^+=2$ and $x_j^-=1$ satisfy set $A$ but not $B$. So, the given set is incorrect.

Comment: Do you have an objective function ?

Answer (score 1):

As $$\underbrace{[-1,1]\times ...\times [-1,1]}_{n\ times}$$

Comment: I am seeking for in terms of  $x_j=x_j^+-x_j^-$

Comment: Then your question doesn't has sense...

Answer (score 0):

Any $x$ in $A$ can be written using $x^+$ and $x^-$ in $B$. Your "counterexample" does not change that fact. In other words, that decomposition would never be the solution if you used the model $B$.

Equivalent statement: I can write every integer as the difference between two non-negative integers, of which at least one is $0$. The fact that I can write $1 = 2-1$ does not invalidate my trivial claim.